# how can i present an introduction view for certain amount f time

Tags: iphone, uiview

several apps use to present an introductionary view for an amount of seconds.How can i code it?i use a timer modal view or what ?thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [link](http://iphoneinaction.manning.com/iphone_in_action/2009/03/creating-a-splash-screen-part-one.html)

or code as follows,

In the interface of your App Delegate:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject
```

{
  UIImageView *splashView;
}

In the implementation:

```
@implementation AppDelegate
```

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];

splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
  splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
  [window addSubview:splashView];
  [window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];

// Do your time consuming setup

[splashView removeFromSuperview];
  [splashView release];
}

Comment: The "splash screen" isn't supposed to be for branding or displaying a logo, it's supposed to look like the default condition of the app so it appears to start up quickly.

Making it stay there for longer would be a violation of the HIG.

Comment: I thought that was the only reason to do a "splash screen".. to display something like a logo while the app is loading up? Why would you want to display the default condition of the app? That would give the user a false sense of the app...

Comment: but how can i consume the time?

Answer (score 0):

You can just bring your intro view to front, and close it using NSTimer.